# Finding indication of ideal ammeter

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, ideal

Would anyone share some tips, advices for solving this task?

[image]

So far, I have dealt with far simplier electric circuit's tasks. This is new to me. Any kind of help or advices are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What standard are these symbols from? I've never seen a voltage source as an arrow in a circle, but E is given a value in volts... And what does "the unit must be placed" mean?

Comment: Oh, unit must be placed means that answer should contain... unit. (A). At least I guess so. 

About standard - I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: What is the resistance of an ideal ammeter.

> I guess 0.

Correct. So what does that tell us about the voltages of all the points on both sides of the ammeter?

More to follow ...

Comment: I guess 0.  (10char)

Comment: That the voltage is 0 because if U = I*R and R = 0, then U = 0?

Comment: Well, it will be zero if we call it zero which we can as there is no ground reference shown. We can make that ground if we want. OK. Now park those ideas and start to look at the loop or "mesh" currents. There is a good, if slightly long, tutorial on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-dc-circuit-analysis/a/ee-mesh-current-method). Post an annotated version of your circuit in your question and type in the equations. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar if required.